# Hard coded repeating elements

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to refactor this code to avoid repetition and to avoid hard-coding of the number of elements?

```
     <td>
         <asp:hiddenfield id="KurseURLImageHiddenField1" value="" runat="server"/>
         <asp:hiddenfield id="KurseURLImageHiddenField2" value="" runat="server"/>
         <asp:hiddenfield id="KurseURLImageHiddenField3" value="" runat="server"/>
         <asp:hiddenfield id="KurseURLImageHiddenField4" value="" runat="server"/>
         <asp:hiddenfield id="KurseURLImageHiddenField5" value="" runat="server"/>
         <asp:hiddenfield id="KurseURLImageHiddenField6" value="" runat="server"/>
         <asp:hiddenfield id="KurseURLImageHiddenField7" value="" runat="server"/>
     </td>
```

I thought of `<asp:Repeater>`, but is there a simplier solution? If using `Repeater` is the simpliest way, how to proper use it in this case?

Comment: `Which case?` yes there's a lots solution to avoid this like
grid, repeater, listitem,simple for loop, string builder etc etc

Comment: @Justcode. I thought I defined the "case" by the code example. I do not know; what solution is the best; that's why I am asking...

Comment: Best solution is what you know how you deal with it